# Select grouped Shapes in VBA (Visio)

Tags: vba, visio, shapes

I'm trying to run through all the shapes of my current visio document using VBA to export some of the strings from it.

It seems easy but I don't know how to get the grouped shapes.

By doing:

```
Dim vsoShapes AS Visio.Shapes
Dim vsoShape AS Visio.Shape
Set vsoShapes = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes
For Each vsoShape In vsoShapes
  ' my code
  ' my code
Next
```

I'm going to access all the parent shapes. What I want is accessing the shapes of the children. 
Is it possible to access it without ungrouping the grouped (parent) shape?

Comment: you can access the group shapes, ie: `vsoShape.Shapes(1).Name `

Comment: actually regular shapes can have subshapes, for example swimlane...so I don't think this code is valid, you need to figure out which shapes is group by looking into group properties section...

Comment: so maybe this is better way to go: 
If Shp.GroupItems.Count > 0 Then Shp.Ungroup Else ....

Comment: found it: Shape.Type property hold mark if shape is group:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767768.aspx
so after you get group shapes then you can progress with subshapes extraction...cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Shapes` property, i.e. `vsoShape.Shapes(1).Name`.

Full loop:

```
Dim vsoShapes AS Visio.Shapes
Dim vsoShape AS Visio.Shape
Dim i As Integer
Dim shapeCount As Integer

Set vsoShapes = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes
For Each vsoShape In vsoShapes
  shapeCount = vsoShape.Shapes.Count
  If shapeCount > 1 Then
    i = 1
    For i = 1 To shapeCount
      MsgBox vsoShape.Shapes(i).Text
    Next i
  End If
Next
```

Comment: I modified my code in the question to add more precision on how to resolve